# Best way to put facebook, twitter and Google+ share buttons in html?

Tags: html, share, social-networking

i'm searching in google and i see infinite ways to put share buttons in html, but i would prefeer to ask here for the best way to do it. The simplest way and easiest way to achieve it.

I just want to add this to my website:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-513375c7395449c1"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

[You can customize it here: Add This](https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.UTN1vDAvmf8)

Comment: that website doesn't have google plus button :S, also i dont like it because they put their button, and i dont want to show it, i just want google+ facebook and twitter

Comment: okay :D you might like this one http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-tools#

Comment: You can also make your own:

Google + - https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/

Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

twitter - https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons

Comment: If you found this useful can you please accept my answer because I cant do much with 3 reputation :D

Comment: Trust me, I've scoured the internet and this link ( http://goo.gl/DlyPpt) is the easiest way to add social buttons, without HTML coding or third-party software, on to your blog

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has removed the "share" button from their list of plugins.However ,the old codes do work.Consider the "send" button alternatively.

You can try [addthis](http://www.addthis.com/) and get analytics free with it.

[Sharethis](http://sharethis.com/) is also a good option

Answer (score 1):

For a plethora in social share options, I think it's best to go with an existing library, which does all the work for you. One example is the [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com) platform

Comment: that website doesn't have google plus button :S. Also i dont like it because they put their button, and i dont want to show it, i just want google+ facebook and twitter

Comment: Perhaps ShareThis is more to your liking: http://sharethis.com